# How to inject javascript in my UIWebview

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i have a web view, in my webview i want to inject the following javascript code.Please help me thanks..

[image]

Comment: How can i do this idont know any thing about javascript

Comment: The only part of this that is JavaScript is the code between `<script type="text/javascript">skyscanner... ...Callback(main);</script>`. Using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript` will not process the HTML in the image you provided.

Comment: @ThomasNadin how then can be done?? what i need to do ?

Comment: I think you may need to get a better understanding of JavaScript and HTML, then re-evaluate your problem. I honestly don't know how to get the HTML block you gave to bet inputted into the DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"your script"];
```

> [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a):
>
> Returns the result of running a script.
>   - (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script Parameters
>
> script
>
> ```
> The script to run.
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> The result of running script or nil if it fails.
>
> Discussion
>
> JavaScript execution time is limited to 10 seconds for each top-level
>   entry point. If your script executes for more than 10 seconds, the web
>   view stops executing the script. This is likely to occur at a random
>   place in your code, so unintended consequences may result. This limit
>   is imposed because JavaScript execution may cause the main thread to
>   block, so when scripts are running, the user is not able to interact
>   with the webpage.
>
> JavaScript allocations are also limited to 10 MB. The web view raises
>   an exception if you exceed this limit on the total memory allocation
>   for JavaScript. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```

Comment: just putting the above script in place of "your script" in [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"your script"]; will work??

Comment: I don't believe so, look at my comment on your question.

Comment: Is i need to put my script in the method - (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script{}  THen what i need to put in the method [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"your script"]; in the ypur script part. Please help by putting some stuff